# NextJS Server-Side Rendering With Front-End React Query Integration

Tags: reactjs, next.js, seo, react-query

I currently have the following React Query implementation:

```
const { data, isSuccess, isLoading } = useQuery(['myQuery', myParams], async () => {
    return myAjaxCall(myParams);
}, {
    cacheTime: 0
});
```

And I pass the results returned into a custom component:

```
<Results foundRecords={data}/>
```

I am in the process of passing the initial search results into my parent page component so that search engine crawlers are able to see the results on initial page load (search engine bots like Google's web crawler cannot see the initial search results if the requests are made client-side - ie. with `useQuery()`).

In this scenario, what's the best way for me to integrate the initial search value I pass into my component (via NextJS' `getServerSideProps()`) with a `useQuery()` implementation?

Off of the top of my head, it would look something like:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context){
    ...
    return {
       initialData: ....
    }
}

export default function MyPage({initialData}){
    const { data, isSuccess, isLoading } = useQuery(['myQuery', myParams], async () => {
        return myAjaxCall(myParams);
    }, {
        cacheTime: 0
    });

    return (
        <Results foundRecords={initialData || data}/>   
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs recommend to put the data into `initialData` of useQuery. Then, you can just continue to use `data` returned from `useQuery`:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context){
    ...
    return {
       initialData: ....
    }
}

export default function MyPage({initialData}){
    const { data, isSuccess, isLoading } = useQuery(['myQuery', myParams], async () => {
        return myAjaxCall(myParams);
    }, {
        cacheTime: 0,
        initialData
    });

    return (
        <Results foundRecords={data}/>   
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the result for the Google crawlers you need to use Metadata where in your title and descriptions are provided also you need to submit your domain name in Google console

```
export default function Mypage({user}) {
    
      return (
        <>
          <Head>
            <meta charSet="utf-8" />
            <link rel="icon" href="https://www.sample.com/favicon.ico" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
            <title>My page</title>
            <meta name="description" content="this is my page description" />
            //Open Graph meta tags...
          </Head>
          <>Home</>
        </>) 
 }
    
    
export async function getServerSideProps ({ req }) { 
  const user ={...}
  return {props: {user: user}} 
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).